# Math History Reference Request: Open-Access Introduction Textbooks, Recently Published from $2015-2022$

Tags: reference-request, math-history

As of recent, I have deeply read through Stephen Hawking’s “A Brief History of Time”, Thomas Levenson’s “The Hunt for Vulcan”, and Howard Eve’s “Foundations and Fundamental Concepts of Mathematics”. The thing is, I didn’t consider math history to be at all interesting until I have was enthralled in the tidbits of history presented throughout these books, and thus I reached out to a math history professor at my college for further reading material.

However, the books he had told me to get is on the extremely-costly for a college student who cannot afford to buy books on her own outside given scholarship money (Book [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144196052X), [two](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/147046456X), and [three](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0761837493))$^{[1]}$. However, I have had extremely good luck in the past from self-studying open-access materials like the [Combinatorics](https://www.rellek.net/book/app-comb.html) and [Abstract Algebra](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/aata.html) open-access textbooks.

Thus, I am wondering if there exists other Open-Access text books of Math History like the above - preferably recently published, as I have noticed/told that newer published books tend to have less bias, and generally more credibility, now than they did $10$ to $20$ years ago. I have tried my best for the last week to find such books online, but none seemed to fit that online format, nor did I feel comfortable enough that the books I did find would be comprehensive enough. Thus, any suggestions of all forms that are applicable to this is extremely welcomed and appreciated.

---

$[1]$ The simple answer of, “If you find it interesting, and are at a college, just signup for a math history class” isn’t suitable here. Being a MS Math student, all math history classes are not applicable for my degree or transcript, as they only exist for math-ed majors, and my scholarships will reject any classes that don’t apply to my MS degree, so I am not allowed to explore in any way in terms of other math subjects aside from the main-line, big-name subjects. In addition, sitting in classes isn’t allowed by the college registrar or the department, so that legitimately isn’t an option as well.

**Edit:**

- Pirating textbooks, or finding the pdfs of certain books from Google with no context of where they come from is not an option. Please do not offer that as a suggestion in comments or as an answer, for obvious DMCA reasons and such.
- This should be something I am able to have access to without having a deadline of turning it back in (i.e. a library or professor).

Comment: 1) Can't you just sit in a class without registering? 2) Maybe the library of your university has these books so you don't have to buy them.

Comment: @PhoemueX That’s explicitly frowned upon in our department, I have tried that with other subjects and have been told to leave. I would like the pleasure of being able to have constant access to this reading material, and not have to return it in any form at the end of the semester. I tend to re-read books until they basically disintegrate, and that takes a lot of time for me, more so than a semesters worth of time. However, they do not have the first two books mentioned, and the latter has been checked out until the end of the semester

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just pirate the books you were recommended? It's extremely easy to find pdfs of your books 1 and 2, and while I couldn't quickly find book 3, I didn't look very hard at all. If you don't like that approach, seeing as your professor suggested them in the first place, it's likely that he has at least one copy of each, which he might be willing to lend you. Though you said you like to repeatedly reread books, so maybe that has similar problems to the library suggestion.

Comment: *"for an academic site this shouldn't have to be mentioned"* I think you'd be surprised how common piracy is in academia, especially with how scummy and exploitative the publishing system is. If you want to buy books though, I'd be surprised if you can find recent texts that are simultaneously thorough and cheap.

Answer (score 1):

### Recent Open Access Books:

(2020) [Making up Numbers, A History of Invention in Mathematics](https://www.openbookpublishers.com/books/10.11647/obp.0236)

#### Standalone, $2000-2020$ Open Access E-Books:

[Mathematics and Its History](https://jontallen.ece.illinois.edu/uploads/537.F18/Papers/MathematicsandItsHistory-johnStillwell.pdf)

[History of Mathematics by Burton](https://jontalle.web.engr.illinois.edu/uploads/298/HistoryMath-Burton.85.pdf)

[A History of Mathematics by Florian Cajori](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31061)

[A Short Account of the History of Mathematics by W. W. Rouse Ball](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31246)

[History of Modern Mathematics by David Eugene Smith](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/8746)

[The number-system of algebra treated theoretically and historically](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/17920)

### Book Archives:

[Online Historical Maths Textbooks from the 16th to 19th Centuries](https://www.resourceaholic.com/p/digitised-antique-maths-textbooks.html)

[Online Books Page - Math History](https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/browse?type=lcsubc&key=Mathematics%20%2D%2D%20History)